# Replacing hoses in spa manifold

Tags: plumbing

Im replacing a damaged spa manifold.  The hoses in my spa are numbered.  But does it matter how you put the hoses back in the new manifold.  Because there are 6 hoses that are difficult to reach and I will probably lose the order when I cut them.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where the lines connect to the manifold. Also I extend the lines and loop them so they are easier to work with.
I have had to replace hundreds of manafolds